# Integration with multidimensional delta function.

Tags: limits, improper-integrals, dirac-delta

I'm am trying to solve an integral of the form $$I=\lim_{t\to-\infty}\int_{0}^{4\sin^2(\pi t/N)}\delta(x-a)f(x)\hspace{1mm}dx.$$

Since, (I'm probably wrong to assume this, since the limit of this function does not exist)$\lim_{t\to-\infty}4\sin^2(\pi t/N)$ oscillates between $[0,4]$. Could I say that $$I=f(a)$$ when $0<a<4$?

EDIT:
I simplified the actual problem, but I will write it out in full now.
I have to solve the following:
$$I=\displaystyle\sum_{\boldsymbol{k}\in\mathbb{Z}^4}\int_{0}^{\infty}d^4n\hspace{1mm}\delta\left(\lambda-E+c^2\left(\sin^2(\pi n_1/N)+\sin^2(\pi n_2/N)+sin^2(\pi n_3/N)+\sin^2(\pi n_4/N)\right)\right)\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i\boldsymbol{k}\cdot\boldsymbol{n}}.$$ Where $c$ and $N$ are constants. Basically, what I've tried is to turn the sine terms into a vector $\boldsymbol{a}=(\sin(\pi n_1/N),\sin(\pi n_2/N),\sin(\pi n_3/N),\sin(\pi n_4/N))$, and re-parameterise the exponent e.g., $$\mu_i=\frac{k_i\cdot n_i}{\sin(\pi n_i/N)},$$ there the exponential term is $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{\mu}}$ and $i=1,2,3,4$. But when I change the variables to $\boldsymbol{a}$, the top limit of integration becomes undefined... The reason for the re-parameterisation of the exponent is so then the solution is a Bessel function. I hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't look as if it makes sense. When $a$ is inside the integration interval the value of the integral is $f(a)$ and otherwise zero (set aside the problems when on the boundary). What are you supposed to do with this integral?

Comment: Could I just cut the integral at the points where the sine function is bounded? so  $\int_{\mathbb{R}}dn_1\rightarrow\int_{-1}^{1}dn_1$.

Comment: The 4 dimensional integral makes perfect sense. I'll think about how to treat it. But changing variables when dealing with delta-functions is delicat. Do you want to take some kind of $N\rightarrow \infty$ limit?

Comment: I suppose the integral goes from $0$ to $\infty$ in all four variables. Then there is (for suitable values of $\lambda,E,c$ a rather complicated 3D surface in the 4D-space so that the argument of the delta-fct vanishes. But then it also vanishes for all $n+m$ with $m\in {\Bbb Z}^4$. It looks as if it diverges? Or perhaps you don't really want to integrate to $\infty$?

Comment: In theory I would take the $\lim_{N\to\infty}$, because the integral corresponds to the spectral density in quantum mechanics, and the choice of $N\rightarrow\infty$ corresponds (in my case) to the classical limit. My previous calculation involved evaluating the Dirac delta with one variable, re-scalling and using the method of stationary phase as $N\rightarrow\infty$. And yes, the sum is not meant to converge because of the nature of trace formulas in semiclassical mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Discussion rather than answer (but too big for a comment): I sort of see the origin of the problem. It still looks to me as if you should only integrate over one period in the $n$'s ? Like from $0$ to $N$ (possibly $2N$) in each $n_i$.

For the sum over $k$'s it looks like evaluations of the integrand.
To simplify things, consider in 1D (without worrying about convergence, and for suitable $C$, and $\phi$ being the expression in the integral apart from the exponential at the end):
$$ \hat{\phi}_p = \int_0^{N} \phi(n) e^{2\pi i  p n/N} dn,\  p\in Z \ \
\mbox{and} \ \ \phi(m)=C\sum_{p\in Z} \hat{\phi}_p e^{-2\pi i p m/N} $$
Seems that you are only summing over terms with $p=Nk$ so you are calculating (apart from  missing pre-factors): $$\sum_{k\in Z}\int_0^N \phi(n) e^{2\pi i  k n} dn =\sum_{k\in Z} \hat{\phi}_{Nk}= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\phi(m).$$ 
As I said, this suggest that you should only integrate over 1 period. The last also seems to have a reasonable limit as $N\rightarrow \infty$. Is this a reasonable direction for you problem (before attacking the evaluation of the last sum)?

Comment: It seems like you have used the Poisson summation formula to get from the integral to the sum. The integral in question actually came from using the summation formula on the sum to get the integral.

Comment: Must admit that I suspected this might be the case. And the integral to infinity is perhaps because you sum $\phi$ over all integers? As the integrand is periodic in $n$ I suppose it suffices to make sense out of it when integrating over a period (and anyway you have to regularize all of it afterwards)